# Android recycler view not showing the output properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

First of all, PLEASE HELP ... I have done almost everything to figure out and now I am here !

1st confusion is: why on earth Async class works so slow, I am using the click event to fetch some data from api, while using SYSO to see the output of populated array in Android monitor, it nearly took 4,5 seconds every time to populate the arraylist with 20 elements. There must be something very wrong which i dont know right now ....

Activity code is :

```
Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_news);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Get Request
    String url = "MY URL HERE";
    new JSONAsync(getApplicationContext()).execute(url);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainNews.this, JSONAsync.dataArray);
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Async class is written as:

```
Context context;
public static List<Data> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();
public JSONAsync(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    dataArray.clear();
}
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        return downloadUrl(params[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public boolean downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = null;
    int response;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        response = conn.getResponseCode();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        if (response == 200) {
            String responseBody = convertToString(conn.getInputStream());
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("Output is: ....."+jobj);
                Data data = new Data();
                data.setId(jobj.getInt("id"));
                data.setHeading(jobj.getString("heading"));
                data.setBrief(jobj.getString("brief"));
                data.setDate(jobj.getString("date"));
                String imageURL = "http://paktribune.com/images/news/";
                imageURL = imageURL.concat(jobj.getString("limage"));
                data.setImage(getBitmapFromURL(imageURL));
                dataArray.add(data);
            }

            return true;
        } else return false;

    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }

}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageURL) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = null;
    try {
        int responseCode;
        URL url = new URL(imageURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode==200)
        {
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
         myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
       }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return myBitmap;

}

public String convertToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

    if (result == false) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

And the adapter is :

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
List<Data> dataArray;
private int lastPosition = -1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataArray) {
    this.dataArray = dataArray;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data current = dataArray.get(position);
    holder.textView1.setText(current.heading);
    holder.textView2.setText(current.date);
    holder.textView3.setText(current.brief);
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(current.image);
    setAnimation(holder.relativeLayout, position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataArray.size();
}

public static class CustomViewHolder extends admin.myproject.CustomViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        textView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        textView3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brief);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Relative);
    }

}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {

    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me why the app moves to the next activity when i click some button before the loop in `doInBackground` completes. 
I am clearing the dataArray and also updating the `notifyDataSetChanged()`. If i use the `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `doInBackground()` or in `postExecute` method, it just points the Null pointer exception so this is the reason I am using it in adapter but i think it's okay to use it there as well.

PLEASE HELP guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed and the implementation is vulnerable to many problematic issues.

1) Async task, as its name suggets performs its task **asynchronously**. That is, the line `new JSONAsync(getApplicationContext()).execute(url);` returns immediately and execution continues in the activity. As you tell the adapter that data is ready, it most probably is not ready and async task is trying to do its job in the mean time.

2) Using the static member to communicate in a multi-threaded environment is prone to errors. Instead, implement a listener interface in your activity and let the async task call the listener's method in `onPostExecute`. Only then tell the adapter about the data change.

```
private List<Data> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();
private IAsyncTaskListener listener;
public JSONAsync(Context context, IAsyncTaskListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}
public interface IAsyncTaskListener {
    void onCompleted(List<Data> dataArray);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    this.listener.onCompleted(dataArray);
}
```

Your activity can implement `IAsyncTaskListener`

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements JSONAsync.IAsyncTaskListener {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<Data> dataArray) {
        recyclerViewAdapter.setData(dataArray);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_news);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get Request
        String url = "http://paktribune.com/api/newsList";
        new JSONAsync(getApplicationContext(), this).execute(url);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new  RecyclerViewAdapter(MainNews.this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    }
}
```

You would provide a method to change the adapter's data. In the listener callback, you set the data on the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on it, to inform the adapter about the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, helpful in understanding about what AsyncTask is! 

One thing I want to know, when you say provide the setData() method, you meant set the dataArray in RecyclerViewAdapter  class like
public void setData(List<Data> dataArray){
this.dataArray = dataArray
}

 so that onCreateView(), onBindView() getItemCount() have access to the data ! Right ... 

I have done this but it is pointing NPE.

I am asking this because I am almost a beginner in android and dont really have a firm grip in this area

Comment: Got it ! And thanks for your guidance. It really helped :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Picasso** or **Glide** library for downloading images. Those libraries might provide faster downloads, their cache handling is better.